# Where are firewalld rules stored on disk?

Tags: rhel, firewalld

The title says it all. I'm curious where firewalld stores the rules on disk. Just for giggles I want to try editing them without `firewall-cmd`.

I saw [here](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/an-introduction-to-firewalld/#:%7E:text=You%20can%20edit%20the%20rules,to%20add%20specific%20firewall%20rules.) mention of a direct rules file, but that isn't in the mentioned location on my system.

Answer (score 1):

From https://firewalld.org/documentation/configuration/directories.html:

> The system or user configuration stored in /etc/firewalld is either created by the system administrator or by customization with the configuration interface of firewalld or by hand. The files will overload the default configuration files.

Comment: I had seen that previously - where are the rules specifically in that? That folder is the totality of the config, but I haven't seen a file that specifically contains the rules.